# How to allow the translation of menu links provided by my_module.links.menu.yml

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

I have the `Configuration Translation` module installed in a multilingual site and I am able to translate any menu created with the UI.... This is fine!!

I have a module which is creating some menus with the help of a yml static file: `my_module.links.menu.yml`

Unfortunately,

1-I couldn't translate any title/description (created in the yml) through in the UI as the translation tab is "locked" with this message : *This link is provided by the xxx module. The title and path cannot be edited.*

2-the **User interface translation** page (`/admin/config/regional/translate`) couldn't find the titles/descriptions (created in the yml) that I would like to translate

**More to add**: I have checked **Custom menu link** in the **Content language an translation** page (`/admin/config/regional/translate`) but this doesn't change anything... What is the purpose of this option?

...If someone can help me on this, I assume I will be able to use the provided solution to translate items created in other yml static files like `my_module.links.action.yml`

Comment: Did you ensure you visited a page with these menu items at least once in the target language before trying to translate it at user interface translation?

Comment: You are right: my admin interface was in English and after having changed this setting in my profile, all the strings were available in the User interface translation page. If you want, you can add this answer and I will vote for it.

Comment: I assume that ckecking **Custom menu link** in Content language and translation page allow the translation of menu links added trough the UI?

Comment: I assume they are basically just treated like t-strings so I don't think any other action needs to be performed in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you visited a page with these menu items at least once in the target language before trying to translate them at user interface translation. They need to be picked up first before appearing there and can only then be translated like any other UI string.